# Using for loop to randomize a variable and run a linear model many times

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I'm really new to R and I've got a task but I've got no idea how to go about it.

I've created a scatterplot, and I need to randomize a variable, and run a linear model of this randomized variable with another (unchanged) variable, before plotting a linear regression line (1,000 of them) on my one scatter plot, using a loop.
This is where I'm at:

```
asample <-numeric(1000)  
for (i in 1:1000) {
Randomised_sample <- sample(MYdata$Variable1)
Linearmodel <- lm(Randomised_sample~(MYdata$Variable2)
summary(Linearmodel)
asample[i] <- coefficients(Linearmodel)
}
```

As you can probably see, I have no idea what I'm doing. Any help is much appreciated, I've been searching for hours. I know I need an abline with the slope etc., but I don't know where to put this / how to make the above work.

Comment: This is a simple way to plot your model: http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/linear-models-r-plotting-regression-lines/ . You have to add new points and ablines sequentially on the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for?  But I have to admit, I'm still a little confused what exactly you are trying to do.

```
set.seed(12345)
x1<-rnorm(n=1000, mean=1, sd=1) #simulating data
y <-rnorm(n=1000, mean=2, sd=2) #simulating data
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(y, x)) #combining data into data frame


coefs<-matrix(nrow=1000, ncol=2) #coefficient matrix to hold betas

for(i in 1:1000){ #for loop

samp<-sample(1:1000, 10) #collecting a sample of size 10 without replacement

fit<-lm(y~x, data=mydata, subset=samp)#finding the fit for the 10 sampled observatoins

coefs[i,1]<-as.numeric(fit$coefficients[1]) #saving beta0
coefs[i,2]<-as.numeric(fit$coefficients[2]) #saving beta1

}
```

Does this help?

Comment: To clarify, I have a non normal distribution of some data. I want to randomise my data, then see if this changes the pattern compared to my original data (it should be different, as it's due to chance). So, I want to shuffle one of my variables, perform a linear model with this randomised variable, then plot the regression line on a plot. I want to use a loop to do this 1,000 times on the same plot (1,000 lines on one plot). I think your suggestion is not quite what I'm after?